# Change WizardStep button text

Tags: sapui5, wizard

How can I rename the button text (default "step 1" till "step n") of each `WizardStep`?.

For the entire `Wizard` the text of the finish button can be set by setting the property `finishButtonText`. But there is no similar property for the `WizardStep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no robust, proper way of changing the next button text (that I could find).

But here are two workarounds that might help while someone else gives a better answer:

The "next button" is the last control of the content of **the current** wizard step

`myWizardStep.getContent()[lastIndex].setText("new text"); /*note that after the button is pressed, the control will no longer be a part of the WizardStep, and lastIndex won't reference the button's index anymore*/`

Another (not great) solution:
The generated id of the button is the `id` of the `Wizard` (not the `WizardStep`) + `-nextButton`. So if you have a wizard `__xmlview13--myWizard`, the next button will always be `__xmlview13--myWizard-nextButton`, which you can get using `sap.ui.getCore().byId(nextButtonId)`and then `.setText()`, etc.

Both workarounds are just a temporary solution, and the button text **will** change after being pressed, because you are working with the same instance of `Button`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way. Here is how I achieved it.

Step 1. Deactivate the standard buttons using showNextButton="false" on the Wizard control.
Step 2. In each of the WizardSteps' content, have your own buttons (As the last control) with the required text. 
Step 3. In the press event of the custom buttons you added, do the validation (consider using API validateStep) and call nextStep() API of the Wizard control.

Comment: I think this is much cleaner than messing with elements and IDs in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look up the explored reference for the Wizard control?
Each Wizard Step title can be edited via the "title" parameter
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Wizard/preview

Otherwise please give a code example from your application

Comment: Yes of course. But unfortunately the title property of the wizard step is intended for the title of the section (is shown in the top left corner of each wizard step) and does not mean the title for the next step button.

Comment: I think that the question was asking about the "Next" button that appears at the bottom of the wizard step when it is validated and not the step title. For this, I think the answer given by krisho is probably the cleanest and most effective.