# SAPUI5: WizardControl - Change Text on Button and add buttons

Tags: wizard, sapui5

I am using the wizard control and i was trying to modify the text in the button for the next step also add some buttons inline with it. I have a screenshot here of what it currently by default looks like and what i wanted to achieve.

**Current:**

[image]

**Target:**

[image]

Can you guys please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Below link has a workaround
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097994/change-wizardstep-button-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change WizardStep button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097994/change-wizardstep-button-text)

Answer (score 2):

I asked a friend who did something like that. Ha just deactivated the button (using `showNextButton="false"`) and made one himself.

Making a customized Button will solve your problem for sure.

Your custom buttons should have a controller function that changes the steps of the wizard. `this.getView().byId("wizID").nextStep()`

Comment: can you please share how he deactivated the button? and maybe share some piece of code how he recreated the same functionality? Thank you.